# OpenGL projection question: Why I can't see anything on the screen?

Tags: opengl, glut

```
void init (void)
{
    glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    //gluLookAt(x0, y0, z0, xref, yref, zref, Vx, Vy, Vz);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluPerspective(45, 2, -1, 1);
    //glFrustum(xwMin, xwMax, ywMin, ywMax, dnear, dfar);
    //gluPerspective(45.0, 45, -1, 1);
}

void displayFcn (void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);
    glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_LINE);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.1, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.50, 0.866025, 0.0);    
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void reshapeFcn(GLint newWidth, GLint newHeight)
{
    glViewport(0,0,newWidth, newHeight);

    winWidth = newWidth;
    winHeight = newHeight;

}
void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(400,200);
    glutInitWindowSize(winWidth, winHeight);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(displayFcn);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshapeFcn);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Could someone explain a little bit and give suggestions how to make that triangle visible.

Comment: What I can see is an empty window with white background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you're allowed to set 'zNear' negative.  That will do weird things to the depth buffer and mean that you see things behind the eye.  [Docs say it's *always positive*](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml).  You're also liable to get somewhat strange results if you fix the aspect ratio to 2, regardless of the aspect ratio of the window.

You also need to set the current matrix back to MODEL_VIEW as datenwolf has shown.  You don't *need* to use gluLookAt, but you need to do something to move the triangle away from the origin where the eye is located.  You could do that by setting the z component to some negative value, or by applying a translation before the vertices:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(0,0,-5);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.1, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.50, 0.866025, 0.0);    
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: I totallz missed that. However negative values would also work in perspective mode. Only at the origin there"d be a singularity. The projection looks like two pyramids connected on their tips.

Comment: @datenwolf It's true that the matrix math works to apply the perspective even when zNear is negative.  But I can't think of how the depth buffer could possibly work.

Comment: for the negative transformed Z values you'll see inverted depth sorting.

Answer (score 2):

*gluPrespective* and *gluLookAt* multiply on top of the current matrix on the selected stack. You need to load an identity first to make sense. Also you need to set a viewport before rendering. Best practice is to set all matrices and the viewport in the display function, and nowhere else. Sticking to that rule will make your life a lot easier. Also in OpenGL one usually doesn't have a dedicated initializtion phase. Resources are loaded on demand.

```
void displayFcn (void)
{
    glViewport(0,0,winWidth, winHeight);

    glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, 2, 1, 10);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(x0, y0, z0, xref, yref, zref, Vx, Vy, Vz);

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);
    glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_LINE);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            glVertex3f(0.1, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.50, 0.866025, 0.0);    
    glEnd();

    glFinish();
}

void reshapeFcn(GLint newWidth, GLint newHeight)
{
    winWidth = newWidth;
    winHeight = newHeight;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(400,200);
    glutInitWindowSize(winWidth, winHeight);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");

    glutDisplayFunc(displayFcn);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshapeFcn);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```